# Autowiring repository gives null in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, interface, crud-repository

When I try to @Autowire my repository interface extending crudrepository, the autowired reference becomes null. It only happens when I use spring.xml (xml-based configuration) to get my service class object into the controller. Spring.xml does not allow me to create beans for my repo because it requires a class, whereas the repo is an interface.

Error is

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
at com.myspringproject1.service.SignupService.doSignup(SignupService.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.myspringproject1.controller.TestController.doSignup(TestController.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
```

spring.xml

```
<bean ..... >
<context:annotation-config/>
    
    <bean id="signupServiceBean" class="com.myspringproject1.service.SignupService"></bean>
    <!-- <bean id="StudentRepoBean" class="com.myspringproject1.repo.StudentRepo"></bean> --> //commented. repo interface bean
     
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myspringproject1.repo"/>
    
</beans>
```

Controller.class

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "signup")
    public ModelAndView doSignup(HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("spring.xml"));
        SignupService signupService = (SignupService) factory.getBean("signupServiceBean");
        
        
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        
        boolean result = signupService.doSignup(request);
        if (result == true) {
            User newUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
            mv.setViewName("signup_result");
            mv.addObject("newUser", newUser);
            return mv;
        }
    
        else {
            mv.setViewName("signup_result");
            mv.addObject("newUser", null);
            return mv;
        }
    }
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

}

Service class.
```

@Service
public class SignupService {

```
@Autowired
private StudentRepo studentRepo;
    User result = studentRepo.save(user); // This fails as studentRepo is coming null.
```

I would appreciate your help in resolving this issue. The whole project works when I don't use spring.xml and just use @component over my service class and autowire it as well in my controller.

I doubt if autowire + xml based config works together!

Comment: Don't... This is so wrong. Don't construct an `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` because you need a bean, instead autowire the `UserService` in the controller.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I started to learn Spring so would like to test each behaviour to understand Sping for a real world application. Thx. Any advise please to fix this? I am using STS Spring boot.